# Corlette-Simpson correspondence over nodal curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, soft-question, hodge-theory

As we know that over a smooth projective variety $X/\mathbb{C}$,  there is a correspondence between semi-simple flat bundles and polystable Higgs bundles with vanishing Chern classes, through differential geometric objects-Harmonic bundles.

On Open varieties $X-D$, with $D$ normal crossing, we also have a modified correspondence given by Simpson and T. Mochizuki: The category of polystable regular filtered flat bundles with trivial Chern classes is natural equivalent to the category of polystables regular filtered Higgs bundles with trivial Chern classes, via the category of Tame Harmonic bundles over the open variety $X-D$. The tameness condition of Harmonic bundles gives a good estimate for the upper bounded of curvatures associated to two metric connections (Which is called acceptable), which make it possible to define a functor from category of Tame harmonic bundles to the category of regular filtered Higgs bundles and the category of regular filtered flat bundle, resp.

**Q:** I think it should be nature to ask: is there a definition of "tame Harmonic bundles" over nodal curve $X$? The naive thoughts are: (1) It should come from harmonic bundles on normalization $\eta: \tilde{X}\rightarrow X$ with gluing data along preimages of nodes. Or (2) It should come from tame harmonic bundles on $\tilde{X}-\eta^{-1}(S)$, where $S$ is set of nodes on $X$, with compatible conditions along the two punctures corresponding to the same node.

Any references are appreciated.